# Implementing OpenId on my own website

Tags: openid

I want to implement OpenId on my website so that users can login from various sites, just like [stackexchange](http://www.stackexchange.com) login system works.
But I'm confused of some common terms like OpenId Provider, consumer, server. which one should I have to install for OpenId login system to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your web site should implement an OpenID Consumer.

Comment: But which PHP library for OpenId should I use.